# How to directly download a source package installation package tarball from a URL?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, url

This is my first question. Quick background: I am an undergrad doing a bioinformatics class in which we use Linux. I have minimal background in Linux and I am having an issue with one of the problems for my homework.

As the title says, I need a "single command" that I can use to download a source package from the package's URL in my working directory. I have searched everywhere and I can't find anything. If it helps, I have to do a non-root install on a class server.

Package I am trying to download: http://www.tree-puzzle.de/#download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download trough commandline:

```
wget -c http://www.tree-puzzle.de/tree-puzzle-5.2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You answer questions quicker and better than my TA! We were never taught that command thank you!

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why you need the sources but just in case, you can also install it simply with "sudo apt-get install tree-puzzle".

Comment: Sadly, can't do that either. Strictly non-root install. I can't use that command when connected to the school server. But, your answer was perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the tarball from your browser and unpack it somewhere in your home directory.

Change to treepuzzle-5.2/doc and read the install section in the pdf.

You have to walk through a configure/make/make install cycle and are free to determine where the programme is installed by setting a prefix.

It really is all in the docs.

Comment: I can't just download it from the browser. I need to know the command to do so. I have to write it down as part of the answer.